# CRM 2016 Web API issue when calling IncrementKnowledgeArticleViewCount

Tags: odata, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have been following [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt683532.aspx) on calling their new Web API however I am having issues passing it the correct parameters.

I think the issue is with the `Source` parameter which is meant to be an `EntityType`, however I can't find any documentation on how to pass it via a `GET` on an unbound function.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

ps. The `ViewDate` parameter has to be passed in [separately](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/204)

**Call I am making:**

> http://hostname:5555/WPK/api/data/v8.0/IncrementKnowledgeArticleViewCount(Source='67322227-C8F7-E511-810C-005056B608D3',ViewDate=@p1,Location=1,Count=1)?@p1='2016-04-04T17:00:00Z'

**Error Message Returned:**

> {   "Message": "Unable to cast object of type
>   'EdmValidCoreModelPrimitiveType' to type
>   'Microsoft.OData.Edm.IEdmStructuredType'.",   "ExceptionMessage":
>   "Unable to cast object of type 'EdmValidCoreModelPrimitiveType' to
>   type 'Microsoft.OData.Edm.IEdmStructuredType'.",   "ExceptionType":
>   "System.InvalidCastException",   "StackTrace": "   at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataPathHandler.Parse(IEdmModel
>   model, String serviceRoot, String odataPath)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.OData.Routing.ODataPathRouteConstraint.Match(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, IHttpRoute route, String parameterName, IDictionary`2 values,
>   HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.ProcessConstraint(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Object constraint, String parameterName,
>   HttpRouteValueDictionary values, HttpRouteDirection
>   routeDirection)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.ProcessConstraints(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpRouteValueDictionary values, HttpRouteDirection
>   routeDirection)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.GetRouteData(String virtualPathRoot,
>   HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HttpWebRoute.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext)",   "ErrorCode": 500 }

Comment: Looks like a CRM server bug while parsing the OData query. You should report it to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

The source parameter needs to be passed as an OData entity reference. Like so:

```
{"@odata.id":"knowledgearticles(da2500aa-2068-e611-8118-00155d011200)"}
```

The following is the request/response showing the use of this method:

```
GET < org uri >/api/data/v8.1/IncrementKnowledgeArticleViewCount(Source=@p1,ViewDate=@p2,Location=@p3,Count=@p4)?@p1=%7B%22@odata.id%22:%22knowledgearticles(da2500aa-2068-e611-8118-00155d011200)%22%7D&@p2=2016-08-22T04:26.59Z&@p3=1&@p4=10 HTTP/1.1
    Accept: application/json
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
    OData-Version: 4.0

    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Pragma: no-cache
    Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
    OData-Version: 4.0

    {
       "@odata.context":"< org uri >/api/data/v8.1/$metadata#knowledgearticleviews/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.crmbaseentity/$entity",
       "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.knowledgearticleviews",
       "knowledgearticleviewsid":"e32500aa-2068-e611-8118-00155d011200"
    }
```

Just to make this a little easier to read, here is the unencoded URL:

```
< org uri >/api/data/v8.1/IncrementKnowledgeArticleViewCount(Source=@p1,ViewDate=@p2,Location=@p3,Count=@p4)?@p1={"@odata.id":"knowledgearticles(da2500aa-2068-e611-8118-00155d011200)"}&@p2=2016-08-22T04:26.59Z&@p3=1&@p4=10
```

The documentation was recently updated to cover this situation. See [Use Web API functions > Pass reference to an entity to a function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309638.aspx#bkmk_passCrmEntityReference)